# Index out of range : UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to put a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell, but I guess I'm doing wrong... 
So here is my code :

PanierMenuCell is UITableViewCell

```
extension PanierMenuCell : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listProduit.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "PanierCollectionCell"
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PanierCollectionCell else {
            fatalError("erreur de conversion !!")
        }

        cell.ONom.text = listProduit[indexPath.row].nomProduct
        cell.OQtt.text = "x\(listProduit[indexPath.row].nbProduct)"
        cell.OImage.image = UIImage(named: "test")
        cell.backgroundColor = .gray
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is my class calling the UITableViewCell :

```
extension PanierVC : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listPanierProduct.count

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "PanierMenuCell"
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PanierMenuCell else {
                fatalError("erreur de conversion !!")
            }

            let produit = listPanierProduct[indexPath.row].product as! Menu
            let listProduit = produit.getListProducts()
            cell.listProduit = listProduit
            cell.OTotal.text = "Total: \(produit.prix)0€"
            cell.ONomMenu.text = "Menu : \(produit.nom)"

            cell.backgroundColor = .gray
            return cell

        }
```

So here is the problem : 
When I'm using several cell with collectionView inside without scrolling the tableview, that's working well, the problem is when I need to scroll down the tableView (the tableview is so reloading the cell), that's causing an error : "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" in

```
cell.ONom.text = listProduit[indexPath.row].nomProduct
```

The item insides the UICollectionView are king of mixed together, I mean that a tableviewcell will take some items which are suppose to be in other tableviewcell, like if the cell.listproduit was mixed... Don't know how clear I was, but I can explain more if needed.

Any ideas on how I should solve this ? 
Thank's a lot

Comment: you need to debug what value you are returning in numberOfRowsInSection and which index you are accessing in cellForRowAt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload your UICollectionView after changing the data source. This will update the number of items in the collection view.

So after this line:

```
cell.listProduit = listProduit
```

Add this line (Assuming you have a property referencing your UICollectionView):

```
cell.collectionView.reloadData()
```